# Audio Recording Using Earphones/Headset on Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to record a conversation call while using headset/earphones? And if so, is it possible to do it with python script?
As of now, I can only record the audio using the default microphone and speaker of my laptop.

Comment: Earphones and headset  are used for outputting audio instead of inputting audio. Did you mean the headset where there's a mic attached?

Comment: I mean for now, the only thing that I can record in conversation when I'm using headset/earphone during call is my own voice and not capturing the others participants voice. I want to capture the whole conversation

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pyaudio? especially the stream method.

checkout this repo https://gist.github.com/fopina/3cefaed1b2d2d79984ad7894aef39a68

Comment: Thanks for answering. I try to replicate the code but error occurs from mic_client.py line 13 "list index out of range". If possible, can you help me to fix the error or other way around? BTW I am using pyaudio and sounddevice.InputStream on my current code.